# Is 5 entries for an orthogonal matrix enough for reconstruction?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

Let
 $R=\begin{bmatrix}
r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} \\
u_{22} & u_{23} & r_{23} \\
u_{31} & u_{32} & r_{33}    
\end{bmatrix}$ be orthogonal $3 \times{3}$ matrix where entries  $r_{ij}$ are given

and  $u_{ij}$  are unknown.

Question for a general case:

- is it possible to reconstruct matrix $R$ in an unique way i.e. there is only
  one possible set of values $u_{ij}$ for orthogonal matrix $R$ with the known $r_{ij}$ entries ?

*Example:*

$R=\begin{bmatrix}
    -\dfrac{1}{3} &     \dfrac{2}{3}      &     \dfrac{2}{3}   \\
     *  &    *  &   \dfrac{2}{3}    \\
    * &    *  &    -\dfrac{1}{3}  \\
        \end{bmatrix}  $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reason as follows. The second column, thought of as a vector, must be orthogonal to the third column, which means it lies on a certain plane; we know its first entry, which restricts it to a line in that plane; and we know its norm, which restricts it to at most two points on that line. Then the first column must be the cross product of the other two columns (or the negative of the cross product). So in general, there won't be many solutions; and, if you think about what could go wrong with the argument (as in the example Vincent gives), you'll probably be able to work out whether there are any more counterexamples.

Comment: From your answer follows that for values other than {0,0,1,0,0} reconstruction is unique if we take as orthogonal matrix a rotation matrix (det(R)=1). First column gives two points and second column analogously give two points: they are crossings of two parallel lines with a unit circle on a plane orthogonal to the third column and they can be exchanged only by places. But cross product of the first and the second column is only one: the third column - so solution is unique. Am I right ?

Comment: I think it's correct that if you add the condition $\det R=1$ then the reconstruction is unique.

Comment: I'm glad you have confirmed uniqueness of reconstruction for rotation matrix (excluding Vincent's case). Gerry, may I translate your answer  into analytical form what would make formula for reconstruction explicit  and it would be some kind of supplement to your answer? (or maybe you would like to do it, extending this way your answer?)

Comment: Feel free to do as you wish.

Comment: Ok. I'll algebraize your algorithm in the future..

Answer (score 3):

Not in general: take the case where $r_{13} = 1$ and the other $r$'s are $0$. Then the possibilities for the $u_{ij}$ are somewhat restricted (they need to be of the form $\cos \theta, -\sin \theta,  \sin \theta, \cos \theta$) but not uniquely determined.

Comment: But if we exclude this special case ? If you  find other,  not listed above,  counterexample the answer will be complete.

Comment: I think Gerry Myerson's answer is really good in this respect. It gives you a clear way to think about what is so special about the special case and what other similar cases you may want to exclude.

Comment: Yes, It is very geometrical approach and I visualized this situation for myself. In the counterexample you presented, the plane orthogonal to the third column, is simply the plane $x=0$ so for this case we have multitude of solutions.. but if $x=a\neq{0}$ then the solution is unique... (for matrix as a rotation matrix, if we allow additionally also $det(R)=-1$ then there are two solutions )